# A bound for the PDE $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u=\Delta u+ au$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces

Consider the following ODE:
$$\frac{d}{dt}u(t)=au(t)$$
with $t\geq 0$ and initial value $u(0)=u_0$, then we have $$u(t)=e^{at}u_0.$$
Now if we consider the following PDE
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(t,x)=\Delta u(t,x)+ au(t,x)$$ on  a smooth bounded open subset $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ and $u=0$ on the boundary $\partial \Omega$. Do we get an estimation of the form
$$|u(t)|_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq Me^{\omega t}.$$
If yes how to prove such estimation, or where can I find such results?

Comment: You can take the $L^2$ inner product of each side of the equation with $u$. You can note that $(u_t , u) = \frac{d}{d t} \frac12 \| u\|^2$ and rearrange. From there you can apply estimates and use the Grönwall inequality I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplying both sides by $u$ and integrating in $\Omega$, one has
$$ \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}|u(t)|_2^2+\|u(t)\|_2^2=a|u(t)|_2^2. $$
Due to the Poincare Inequality, one attains
$$ \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}|u(t)|_2^2+\lambda_1|u(t)|_2^2\le a|u(t)|_2^2 $$
or
$$ \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}|u(t)|_2^2+(\lambda_1-a)|u(t)|_2^2\le0. $$
Hence
$$ |u(t)|_2^2\le |u(0)|_2^2e^{-2(\lambda_1-a)t} $$
or
$$ |u(t)|_2\le |u(0)|_2e^{-(\lambda_1-a)t}. $$

Comment: Thanks!!! can we do the same but with point-wise estimation $|u(t,x)|\leq$... for each $t\geq 0$ and $x\in \Omega$?